# Trouble with test code

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am attempting to write test code for this simple trigger but it is failing.

This is the trigger :

```
trigger SetOverallContractEndDate on Contract_Terms__c (before update, before insert) {
  for (Contract_Terms__c ct : Trigger.new) {
          if (ct.Auto_Renewal_Contract_End_Date__c== null)
          ct.Overall_End_Date__c= ct.Contract_End_Date__c;
        else
          ct.Overall_End_Date__c = ct.Auto_Renewal_Contract_End_Date__c;  
  }

}
```

This is my test code :

```
@isTest
private class SetContractEndDatesTriggerTest
{

  static TestMethod void SetContractEndDatesTest1()
  {
    Test.startTest();
                // Insert Contract_Terms__c record
    Contract_Terms__c  obj = new Contract_Terms__c(Name = 'test record 001', Contract_End_Date__c =  System.Today() +1, Auto_Renewal_Contract_End_Date__c = System.Today() + 2);
           insert obj;
                 Test.stopTest();
  }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea of what that might be ... ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

why dont you employee Field Updates for this? Configuration over Code

Comment: I guess I could - would that be the better way to do it ?

Comment: yes, when ever you have to option to choose between Configuration - here Workflow Field Update - and Code - your Apex Trigger - to archive a result,  you should go with Configuration. Because maintenance of Configuration is way easier than modifying code and does not necessarily require a DEV

Comment: Ok - so I put it into a Field Update. Simple one line : IF( Auto_Renewal_Contract_End_Date__c = null, Contract_End_Date__c , Auto_Renewal_Contract_End_Date__c ) ; Should do the same thing as that trigger, right ? For some reason it doesn't change the Overall_End_Date__c. Am I missing something here ? I've even checked the "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change" checkbox of the Field Update. I know you can't see everything but sometimes just asking somebody else to look at the same thing can help.

Comment: @Zoom_v check if the Workflow is active, any other WF Rule updating. in addition have a look into the debug log